# However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved - React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, npm, metro-bundler

I have installed the 'react-native-auto-scrolling` package and I get the following error:

```
error: Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module 'react-native-auto-scrolling' from file '.....\Home.js', the package '......\node_modules\react-native-auto-scrollinge\package.json' was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a 'main' module field that could not be resolved ('......\node_modules\react-native-auto-scrollinge\dist\index.js'.
```

I have tried to fix this by adding in the `metro.config.js` the following code:

```
resolver: {   
      sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx'],
},
```

under `module.exports` (as I found that the `Metro` doesn't know how to compile by default `.tsx`) but I still cannot use the package, as it returns me the same error when trying to run `react-native run-android`. As I checked `node-modules` for the package, I have discovered that the package is created using `typescript`. Any help would be appreciated. I've seen a snack that works: [Exemple auto-scrolling](https://snack.expo.io/@minhtc/react-native-auto-scrolling-demo) so I guess it should also work with a bare workflow react native app.